# XML Signature works with random RSA Key but not with key from certificate

Tags: c#, .net, xml, signature

I'm trying to sign an XML Document using the following algorithm  in C# :

> http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256

When I try to sign it with a random RSA Key it works perfectly.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        xmlDoc.Load("hpbtest.xml");
        RSA Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        // Create a SignedXml object.
        PrefixedSignedXML signedXml = new PrefixedSignedXML(xmlDoc);
        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = Key;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])";
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
        env.Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315";
        reference.AddTransform(env);
        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature("ds");
        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml("ds");
        // Append the element to the XML document.
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        xmlDoc.Save("hpbtest.xml");
```

But if I want to use an RSA Key from a Certificate generated by OpenSSL :

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        xmlDoc.Load("hpbtest.xml");
        RSA Key = new GestionCertificat("CN=Bruno").getClePrivee();//Get the private key
        // Create a SignedXml object.
        PrefixedSignedXML signedXml = new PrefixedSignedXML(xmlDoc);
        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = Key;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])";
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
        env.Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315";
        reference.AddTransform(env);
        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature("ds");
        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml("ds");
        // Append the element to the XML document.
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        xmlDoc.Save("hpbtest.xml");
```

I get this error :

> Invalid specified algorithm

In these two examples, my RSA Keys have the same length (2048) and I have no idea why I get this error.

Thank you !

Thomas

Comment: What is `PrefixedSignedXML`? Do you maybe use a third party CMS provider or hardware device?

Comment: `PrefixedSignedXML` is a class inherit of SignedXML to add "ds" prefix on the signature elements.  
I generate my certificates with Makecert. I also tried to generate a certificate with OpenSSL but i had the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem. If it can help someone :

Previously I try to get the private key from the certificate by this way  :

```
RSA Key = new GestionCertificat("CN=EbicsAuth").getClePrivee();//Get the private key
```

This is the code of my class GestionCertificat :

```
String CertificatEncoded;
    String ModulusEncoded;
    String ExponentEncoded;
    RSA Cle;
    RSA ClePrivee;
    X509Certificate2 Certificat;
    public GestionCertificat(String NomCertificat)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        foreach (X509Certificate2 c in certCollection)
        {
            if (c.Subject == NomCertificat)
            {
                cert = c;
                break;
            }
        }
        store.Close();
        Certificat = cert;
        CertificatEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(cert.RawData); //Conversion du certificat en base64
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaprovider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;//Récupération de la clé RSA du certificat
        RSAParameters newparams = rsaprovider.ExportParameters(false);//Extractions des paramètres de la clé
        ModulusEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(newparams.Modulus);//Conversion du Modulus en base64
        ExponentEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(newparams.Exponent);//Conversion de l'Exponent en base64
        Cle = (RSA)cert.PublicKey.Key;
        ClePrivee = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
    }

    public String getCertificatEncoded()
    {
        return this.CertificatEncoded;
    }

    public String getModulusEncoded()
    {
        return this.ModulusEncoded;
    }

    public String getExponentEncoded()
    {
        return this.ExponentEncoded;
    }

    public RSA getClePublique()
    {
        return this.Cle;
    }

    public RSA getClePrivee()
    {
        return this.ClePrivee;
    }

    public X509Certificate2 getCertificat()
    {
        return this.Certificat;
    }
```

But now to get the RSA Key to sign my XML I did this :

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var gestionCertif = new GestionCertificat("CN=EbicsAuth");
X509Certificate2 Cert = gestionCertif.getCertificat();
Key.FromXmlString(Cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
```

And now the signature works !